# cpp function returning garbage string value

Tags: c++, string, return-value, return-type, garbage

I was testing something around string datatype in CPP. I was running the following code:

```
    #include <iostream>
    #include <string.h>
    #include <stdio.h>
    using namespace std;
    char* myname() {
        char str[5] ;
        str[0] = 'a';
        str[1] = 'b';
        str[2] = 'c';
        str[3] = '\0';
        //printf("BEFORE[%s]__", str);
        string aa = str;
        string aa2 = "";
        aa2+=aa[0];
        aa2+=aa[1];
        aa2+=aa[2];
        aa2+=aa[3];
        return &aa2[0];
    }


    int main() {
        printf("AFTER[%s]\n", myname());
        return 0;
    }
```

Compiler Version:

```
    user@822e36b19146:~/data$ g++ --version
    g++ (Ubuntu 5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.6) 5.4.0 20160609
    Copyright (C) 2015 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
    This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
    warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.
```

I am getting garbage values on my machine:

```
    user@822e36b19146:~/data$ g++ -o test test.cpp
    user@822e36b19146:~/data$ ./test
    AFTER[��p��]
    user@822e36b19146:~/data$ ./test
    AFTER[�7���]
```

I tried running the same code on an online compiler. Some are working and some are not.

1. NotWorking: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/ce4bc39767b29e44
2. NotWorking: https://wandbox.org/permlink/C8ATffE4wysy3il0
3. Working: https://ideone.com/NV0mUM
4. Working: http://cpp.sh/8cctv

One strange behavior I am observing that on printing anything before returning. Makes the code working fine. In my tried uncommenting line `//printf("BEFORE...`
Getting the following output:

```
    user@822e36b19146:~/data$ g++ -o test test.cpp
    user@822e36b19146:~/data$ ./test
    BEFORE[abc]__AFTER[abc]
    user@822e36b19146:~/data$ ./test
    BEFORE[abc]__AFTER[abc]
```

Please, anyone, help me in understanding this.

Comment: The `return &aa2[0];` returns a pointer to a local object that is about to be destroyed.  Nothing good can come of that.

Comment: @Eljay Yes, that is right but here read my last paragraph. If I print anything before the return statement it is working all fine. This means the string datatype variable's address did not get destroyed after the function's return.

Comment: _"This means the string datatype variable's address did not get destroyed after the function's return."_  That is incorrect.  It does get destroyed, and what is returned is a dangling pointer to a destroyed object.  Which means anything using that pointer is doing undefined behavior.  And undefined behavior may appear to work as desired.

Comment: @Eljay I was assuming the same thing. But after seeing the results I am getting with string i got confused. Because it is consistently working fine with some print statement inside the function and not working in one case.